Isomorphism as $\Bbb{F}_p$ vector space and Proof of local Tate--Duality $H^1(G_K,E)[p]\cong (E(K)/pE(K))^*$
This is a question regarding Theorem $1.4$ of
https://kskedlaya.org/kolyvagin-seminar/duality.pdf.
Let $E/K$ be an elliptic curve over number field $K$.
Let $p$ be a prime number.
The goal of Theorem $1.4$ claims that $H^1(G_K,E)[p]\cong (E(K)/pE(K))^*$ where $*$ denotes dual.
The proof of Theorem $1.4$ proves $H^1(G_K,E)[p]$ and $E(K)/pE(K)$ has the same dimention as $\Bbb{F}_p$ vector space.
The linked paper proves $E(K)/pE(K)$ injectis into $H^1(G_K,E)[p]^*$, and conclude that they are isomorphic.
But I cannot understand the strategy of proof because once $H^1(G_K,E)[p]$ and $E(K)/pE(K)$ has the same dimention as $\Bbb{F}_p$ vector space, it is clear that $H^1(G_K,E)[p]\cong (E(K)/pE(K))^*$ because they have the same dimmension as $\Bbb{F}_p$ vector spaces.
What am I missing? And what is the basic approach to proving the desired isomorphism?

The statement of the theorem isn't just that these two spaces are isomorphic, it gives an explicit formula for the pairing that induces the isomorphism. This is important for, among other reasons, naturality (which is necessary to study questions along the lines of: what happens to the isomorphism when you have an isogeny of elliptic curves?).
As you say, two finite-dimensional vector spaces of the same dimension over some field $k$ are abstractly isomorphic. But this does not imply that any given particular map between them is an isomorphism, of course. So to prove that a map is an isomorphism, you still have to know that it's either injective or surjective (once you know equidimensionality, there's no need to check both).
